# ¿Es posible Imprimir la Consola de C#?

Tags: c#

Hola podrían decirme si es posible imprimir la Consola en un Proyecto de C#, la cuestión es la siguiente trato de que se refleje el resultado de lo que sucede en el código y ahorita lo hago editando un `Label`
es decir:

```
consola.Text += "Enviando Identity: "+ SB_Identity + "\n";
```

Pero esto se refleja en muy poca velocidad y me gustaría imprimir la consola en la interfaz principal.
Alguien sabe como se puede hacer?

Comment: No entendi porque decis que es muy lento? y podrias colocar un poco mas de tu codigo para entender a que te referis con consola e interfaz principal? Porque si decis consola, seria un proyecto de Consola. Pero hablas de interfaz principal entonces creo que es un Winforms.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es únicamente reportar información de salida puedes usar un control del tipo ListBox e incluirlo en tu formulario y añadir la información que deseas presentar añadiéndola al ListBox:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("Enviando Identity: "+ SB_Identity);
```